# Printing error in cout

Tags: c++, cout

I have a variable which is divided into 3 and 5 bits, and i am able to populate to each section i.e a and b.

```
unsigned char a:3,b:5;
```

How can i print the values of both the section individually. If not how can I print as a whole.

```
 cout << a << b ;
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Why does what you have done not work?

Comment: its printing but a an unknown character  like a small box with bits inside

Comment: `cout << (int)a << (int)b;` . Or declare your vars as `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @M.M thank you its working

Answer (score 0):

```
union Value
{
    unsigned char char_value;
    struct BitValue
    {   
        unsigned char three_bit:3;
        unsigned char five_bit:5;
    } bit_value;
};

int main()  
{  
    Value tmp;
    tmp.char_value=207;
    cout<<(unsigned int)tmp.bit_value.three_bit<<" "<<(unsigned int)tmp.bit_value.five_bit<<" "<<(unsigned int)tmp.char_value<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this is answer.

Comment: please try to provide the correct answer if you have doubts about your answer to the question asked, then you can leave a comment.